# Changing installation directory of CPAN perl module using MinGW

Tags: perl, mingw, perl-module, cpan

I installed MinGW for installing perl modules from CPAN. after successful installation in C:/MinGW, I started msys.bat typed

> cpan
>
> cpan> install File::List

The module installed successfully. But it is not found in lib or site directory of c:/perl.
It is installed in C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\lib\perl5\site_perl\5.8\File instead.

How could I change the installation directory of CPAN modules to c:/perl/site or c:/perl/lib?
I used all default setting of MinGW. OS is Windows 7. Perl version 5.12.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem. I don't have Microsoft Visual C++ redistributable 2008, 2010. I installed it and my problem is solved. May be Perl module builds which requires C compiler required this components.

Anyone ever have similar experience?

Answer (score 0):

*"How could I change the installation directory of CPAN modules to c:/perl/site or c:/perl/lib?"*

It's not clear to me why you would want to do that.  If you used MinGW to install modules from CPAN, it is presumably because you want the advantages of the MinGW toolset (as described at 
http://mingw.org/).  And MinGW presumably knows what it is doing when it installs in the directory you cited.

If you really want to install to `c:/perl/site` or `c:/perl/lib`, you should probably use the `cpan` client that comes with Perl itself.